# Monotouch MKMapKit - changing default map tiles

Tags: iphone, maps, mkmapview, xamarin.ios, tiles

I know that in the google maps API it's possible to replace the existing tiles with my own - and using their tile server - feed my own maps.

i'm interested in doing this using monotouch - is there any way of doing this atm - or does anyone know of a way of achieving this any other way?

w://

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use an UIWebView (or whatever its called) you can host an html page. See [phonegap](http://www.phonegap.com/) for an implementation of this approach (although not a MonoTouch implemenation, which may be for the best thanks to 3.1.3)

Theres an example of google maps js api being used with custom tiles here http://mapwow.com/